# List comprehensions splitting loop variable

Tags: python, split, list-comprehension

I am trying to find out if there is a way to split the value of each iteration of a list comprehension only once but use it twice in the output.

As an example of the problem I am trying to solve is, I have the string:

```
a = "1;2;4\n3;4;5"
```

And I would like to perform this:

```
>>> [(x.split(";")[1],x.split(";")[2]) for x in a.split("\n") if x.split(",")[1] != 5]
[('2', '4'), ('4', '5')]
```

Without the need for running split three times. So something like this (Which is obviously invalid syntax but hopefully is enough to get the message across):

```
[(x[1],x[2]) for x.split(";") in a.split("\n") if x[1] != 5]
```

In this question I am **not** looking for fancy ways to get the 2nd and 3rd column of the string. It is just a way of providing a concrete example. I could for course for the example use:

```
[x.split(";")[1:3] for x in a.split("\n")]
```

The possible solutions I have thought of:

1. Not use a list comprehension
2. Leave it as is
3. Use the `csv.DictReader`, name my columns and something like `StringIO` to give it the input.

This is mostly something that would be a nice pattern to be able to use rather than a specific case so its hard to answer the "why do you want to do this" or "what is this for" kind of questions

**Update:** After being reading the solution below I went and ran some speed tests. And I found in my very basic tests that the solution provided was 35% faster than the naive solution above.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension wrapped around a generator expression:

```
[(x[1],x[2]) for x in (x.split(";") for x in a.split("\n")) if x[1] != 5]
```

Answer (score 12):

Starting `Python 3.8`, and the introduction of [assignment expressions (PEP 572)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) (`:=` operator), it's possible to use a local variable within a list comprehension in order to avoid calling twice the same expression:

In our case, we can name the evaluation of `line.split(';')` as a variable `parts` while using the result of the expression to filter the list if `parts[1]` is not equal to `5`; and thus re-use `parts` to produce the mapped value:

```
# text = '1;2;4\n3;4;5'
[(parts[1], parts[2]) for line in text.split('\n') if (parts := line.split(';'))[1] != 5]
# [('2', '4'), ('4', '5')]
```