# Unpacking list into strings, splitting them and creating a dictionary from there

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using python 3.x and I want to create a dictionary from a list. That is, I have each key and value concatenated in a string, and each entry as an element in a list.

```
my_list = ['val1 key1', 'val2 key2', 'val2 key2']
```

I can split it into two lists using

```
values,keys = zip(*(s.split() for s in my_list))
```

Creating a dictionary from there is easy. Since I still need to do stuff to the keys and values, I do:

```
my_dict = {k[:-1]:float(v) for k,v in zip(keys,values)}
```

Out of mere curiosity, I was wondering If there is a way where to avoid the intermediate lists. In short I need to access each list element, split the string, do something to each split part and input it as key:value pair into a dictionary. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308939/python-list-comprehensions-splitting-loop-variable) question I tried

```
my_dict = {k[:-1]:float(v) for v,k in zip(*(s.split() for s in my_list))}
```

But I get `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`. Then I tried simply using a generator (I *think* it's a generator) inside the dictionary comprehension syntax and it work. But I don't like it, since the second `for` is used only to extract an element from the list:

```
my_dict = {s[1][:-1]:float(s[0]) for s in (s.split(', ') for s in my_list)}
```

This is what I'm currently using and works perfectly, but I'd like to know why the second solution doesn't work. to me, it seems it should, and that my solution uses one to many `for`. I'm aware it's not a super relevant question, but I'd like to learn. Also, I'm open to title suggestions.

EDIT1: Fixed a few syntax errors I had.

EDIT2: A full working and explicit example with expected result, as suggested. I'm still working on making good [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)'s:

```
my_list = ['1.123, name1\n', '2.3234, name2\n', '3.983, name3\n', '4.23, name4\n']
```

The output I want is what I would get if I manually did

```
my_dict = {'name1':1.123, 'name2':2.3234, 'name3':3.983, 'name4':4.23}
```

Method that creates intermediate lists:

```
values,keys = zip(*(s.split(', ') for s in my_list))
print(values)
>>> ('1.123', '2.3234', '3.983', '4.23')
print(keys)
>>> ('name1\n', 'name2\n', 'name3\n', 'name4\n')
my_dict = {k[:-1]:float(v) for k,v in zip(keys,values)}
print(my_dict)
>>> {'name4': 4.23, 'name2': 2.3234, 'name1': 1.123, 'name3': 3.983}
```

Example that I don't know why it does not work:

```
my_dict = {k[:-1]:float(v) for v,k in zip(*(s.split(', ') for s in my_list))}
>>> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Working example that to me, seems it uses one to `for` inside the list/dict comprehension/generator expression:

```
my_dict = {s[1][:-1]:float(s[0]) for s in (s.split(', ') for s in my_list)}
print(my_dict)
>>> {'name4': 4.23, 'name2': 2.3234, 'name1': 1.123, 'name3': 3.983}
```

My actual strings look something like `'0.9493432915614861, zf_AB012_bn_BOS\n'`
, that's why I use a more readable example.

EDIT3: I just learned of the str.strip() method. This makes the line creating the dictionary a bit nicer:

```
my_dict = {s[1].strip():float(s[0]) for s in (s.split(', ') for s in my_list)}
```

Comment: One of the elements of your list contains more than two portions separated by spaces. Probably using `s.split(maxsplit=1)` fixes the error.

Comment: What is your desired output? `for zip(keys,values)` is invalid syntax.

Comment: You are also trying to cast `v` as a float, but it is a string.

Comment: Please post an example case of input and desired output.

Comment: I understood what you meant, but I suggest you take into consideration all these comments and improve your question with a working example.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @Ajax1234, you're right, fixed the mistake. I'm updating the question with a concrete example and expected result.

Comment: If you're using Python 3 (which you should be), `zip` won't actually create a list, but will instead produce an iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def dict_unzip(lst):
    for x in lst:
        yield reversed(x.split(' ', 1))

my_dict = dict(dict_unzip(my_list))
```

But since it's Python3 things are notably simpler actually:

```
my_dict = dict(map(lambda s: reversed(s.split(' ', 1)), my_list))
```

Or even

```
my_dict = dict(reversed(s.split(' ', 1)) for s in my_list)
```

Comment: Thank you! `map` was what I was missing in my repertoire.