# Is there a way to break string into list using list comprehensions?

Tags: python-2.x

Say I have a string of words separated by spaces and commas like

`phrase="Hey John, take that"`

I would like to split the string into a list using list comprehensions to obtain

`["Hey", "John", "take", "that"]`

Any suggestion?

Comment: please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308939/list-comprehensions-splitting-loop-variable

Comment: Thanks a lot man. It worked with: `[y for x in phrase.split(" ") for y in x.split(",") if not (y=="")]`