# List comprehension with split

Tags: python

Input: `["0:start:0","1:start:2","1:end:5","0:end:6"]`

Output: `[[0, "start", 0], [1, "start", 2], ... ]`

This one `[item.split(":") for item in logs]` doesn't convert to int. Tried various ways, but cannot make it to work: `[(int(a), b, int(c)) for item in logs for (a,b,c) in item.split(":")]`

Thanks!

Comment: @GandhiGandhi exactly, don't know if it's a good or bad thing. But it helped me. :)

Comment: @GandhiGandhi - Questions like this are free rep; of course it's active.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```py
 [[int(a), b, int(c)] for a,b,c in [item.split(":") for item in logs]]
```

You came pretty close!

Comment: I think this is my favorite, for its balance of brevity and clarity. One note: you can write the second part as a generator expression rather than a list comprehension -- `(item.split(";") for item in logs)` -- to avoid creating the intermediate list in memory.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a generator expression in the list comprehension:

```
a = ["0:start:0","1:start:2","1:end:5","0:end:6"]
b = [[int(x[0]), x[1], int(x[2])] for x in (item.split(":") for item in a)]
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 'start', 0], [1, 'start', 2], [1, 'end', 5], [0, 'end', 6]]
```

My answer was inspired by: [List comprehensions splitting loop variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308939/list-comprehensions-splitting-loop-variable)

Answer (score 5):

For clarity, I'd do it this way, in two steps:

```
logs = ["0:start:0", "1:start:2", "1:end:5", "0:end:6"]
split_logs = (log.split(':') for log in logs)
result = [(int(a), b, int(c)) for a, b, c in split_logs]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add the `map` function:

```
[(int(i), j, int(k)) for i, j, k  in map(lambda x: x.split(':'), lst)]
```

Answer (score 2):

There comes a point where a list comprehension is complex enough that perhaps you really should just use a `for` loop. However, I think this ends up being pretty readable:

```py
input_list = ['0:start:0', '1:start:2', '1:end:5', '0:end:6']

transformed = [
    [
        int(subitem) if subitem.isdigit() else item
        for part in item.split(':')
    ]
    for item in input_list
]

print(transformed)
>>> [[0, 'start', 0], [1, 'start', 2], [1, 'end', 5], [0, 'end', 6]]
```

It's one list comprehension nested inside another. The inner one iterates through the subitems of each item in the original list, and converts each one to an `int` if it contains only digits.